# HTA becomes unstable when run in IE9 mode

Tags: internet-explorer-9, hta

I'm converting my HTA application to IE9 mode.

To achieve this I've set my doc-type to stict and added the required meta tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
...
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

For some reason my app now crashes VERY VERY frequently. If I remove the meta tag, the problem goes away.

The hta throws this uncought execption debugging is useless since I do not have the mshta.exe's source:

> ```
> Problem signature:
>   Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>   Application Name:   mshta.exe
>   Application Version:    9.0.8112.16421
>   Application Timestamp:  4d76250b
>   Fault Module Name:  mshtml.dll
>   Fault Module Version:   9.0.8112.16447
>   Fault Module Timestamp: 4fc9d776
>   Exception Code: c0000005
>   Exception Offset:   0042e4fc
>   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>   Locale ID:  1043
>   Additional Information 1:   4730
>   Additional Information 2:   4730254975cd5e69c9f98e6774a147ea
>   Additional Information 3:   7e68
>   Additional Information 4:   7e68196790120254f61ecb0212b4aa5b
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
> ```

Where do I turn with this? I'm temped to say it is caused by some sort of bug. If my code does something illegal the HTA should throw a script error instead of this uncought exception. But for some reason I do not expect to be able to call MS to ask them for help...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. However, it seems that there is a conflict between `x-ua-compatible` and doctype, try to use simple `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: I've updated the doctype, but it doesn't help...
It's hard to reproduce the problem, the HTA application is quite complex, it's not just a single page. In this case we are talking about multiple iframes being loaded, most of them getting their date dynamically through AJAX, etc... But, I have one consistent way to reproduce the error on my system. I navigate to a certain page, right click and refresh the page. 9 out of 10 times will result in a crash.. I will test on a  few other machines as well

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` tag is only useful in very simple HTAs which still use HTML5. As soon as you add a frame, a `<hta:application>` tag, it gives you problems. Try taking away `!DOCTYPE` and `PUBLIC="..."` so that the HTML-tag is simply `<html>`. If you still have a problem, you might have something in the body which doesn't work with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` tag. I know that this is annoying, I have the same probem on my HTA and can't use the HTML5 `accept` attribute (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704801/equivalent-to-accept-attribute-in-hta) without my frames and my `<hta:application>` attributes being ignored. Try to delete the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` tag or to change it to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`.