# Equivalent to accept attribute in HTA

Tags: html, hta

Is there an equivalent of the `accept` attribute (in `<input type="file">`) which works in HTA (or in IE7 because HTA works like IE7)?

Comment: Actually [HTA can also work like IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519). Just use HTML5 DTD and `x-ua compatible` `meta` tag with value `ie=edge`. This needs you to have IE11 installed ofcourse.

Comment: Perfect. You could have posted that as an answer.

Comment: Well, a new answer would be only a dup of the linked answer. Notice, that HTA has been deprecated starting from IE10, hence there are some limitations to the HTA window properties when running in IE=10 or later mode.

Comment: I noticed that... It doesn't support frames or the `<hta:application>` tag. I answered only after testing it on a simple HTA with only a `<title>` and a `<input type="file">`.

Comment: Unfortenately that's the case. There's some discussion about this in the comments below the answer linked in my comment above. `frameset` and `frame`s are not supported in HTML5, hence they can't be used in IE9+ modes.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both the features provided by an `<hta:application>` tag and use IE10 and IE11 features, such as the `accept` attribute in `<input type="file">`, by splitting your HTA into two parts as shown in the example below.

Note: The `SingleInstance` attribute has to be replicated with code.

IE11-Mode-Test.hta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<HTA:Application
  ID=oHTA
  Navigable=yes
  Application=yes
  Icon="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
  Caption=yes
  Sysmenu=yes
  Scroll=no
  SingleInstance=yes
>
<script language="vbscript">
MyName = "IE11-Mode-Test"
MyNameHTA = MyName & ".hta"
MyNameHTM = MyName & ".htm"

Window.ResizeTo 100,100
Window.MoveTo -2000,-2000
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Function ProcessCount(Exe,File)
  ProcessCount = 0
  Set oProcesses = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
  For Each oProcess In oProcesses
    If InStr(oProcess.CommandLine,"\" & Exe) Then
      If InStr(oProcess.CommandLine,"\" & File) Then
        ProcessCount = ProcessCount + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Function

If LCase(oHTA.singleInstance)="yes" And ProcessCount("mshta.exe",MyNameHTA)>1 Then Window.Close
location.href = MyNameHTM
</script>
```

IE11-Mode-Test.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
<script>
x = 800; y = 620;
window.resizeTo(x,y);
window.moveTo ((screen.availWidth - x)/2, (screen.availHeight - y)/2)
document.title = "IE11-Mode-Test";
function PlayVideo(){v1.src = f1.value;}
</script>
<style>
.fc {display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:50px; border:3px solid}
#f1 {width:100%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fc">
  <p>HTA in IE11 Mode</p>
</div><br>
File input with Accept attribute:<br>
<input type="file" id="f1" accept="video/*" oninput="PlayVideo()"><br><br>
<video width="100%" controls>
  <source id="v1" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not understand what this does? Does it just open a window off the screen and prevents from opening a second? It seems more interesting to rename the second file to .hta and run the player, because it alone recognize the `accept`.

Comment: @Zano No, that's not what it does. If you rename the second file with an HTA extension and just run it directly, the **accept** will work, BUT you will lose the ability to set any options under **HTA:Application**, as that section is not supported beyond IE 9. By splitting the script into two files, as shown, you retain the **HTA:Application** options AND can use features that are only available in IE 10 and IE 11.