# Oninput event not triggering in HTA using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, hta

I'm learning JavaScript using some examples I've found online. And in working on an HTA I've come a cropper trying to work out why the "oninput" event won't trigger. I've included the relevant code below to demonstrate my issue. Please note I'm using Edge compatibility in the meta tag. I would appreciate any information on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <hta:application 
    id=""
    applicationname=""
    border="thin"
    borderstyle="normal"
    caption="yes"
    icon=""
    maximizebutton="no"
    minimizebutton="yes"
    scroll="yes"
    levelintaskbar="yes"
    singleinstance="yes"
    sysmenu="yes"
    version="1.00"
    windowstate="maximize"
    />
</head>  
<style>
body {
background-color: lightgray;
color: darkred;
font-family: "Arial";
}

h3 {
text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function level() {
f = document.getElementById("x").value;
document.getElementById("x_out").innerHTML = f + " factor";

switch(document.getElementById("y").value * 1){
    case 0: 
    type = "alpha"; 
    break; 
    case 1: 
    type = "beta"; 
    break;
    case 2: 
    type = "gamma"; 
    break;
    case 3: 
    type = "delta"; 
    break;
}    
document.getElementById("y_out").innerHTML = type;

v = document.getElementById("z").value * 1;
document.getElementById("z_out").innerHTML = v;
}
</script>

<body onload="level()">
<h3>Test</h3>
<p>
X:
<br>
<input type="range" id="x" min="40" max="6000" onclick="level()">
&emsp;<span id="x_out"></span>
</p> 
Y:
<br>
<input type="range" id="y" min="0" max="3" onchange="level()">
&emsp;<span id="y_out"></span>
<p>
Z:
<br>
<input type="range" id="z" min="0" max="100" oninput="level()">
&emsp;<span id="z_out"></span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MSHTML, (the rendering engine used by MSHTA and IE), `oninput` will trigger with input type `text`, but will be ignored for input type `range`.

It's not a good idea to try to use an HTA to learn modern JavaScript. HTAs support [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), so you will constantly run into situations like this. If you just want to work with a local file, save your examples with a `.htm` extension and run them in any modern browser, such as Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc.

If you really want to write HTAs (i.e. in order to write code that has full access to the machine like an `Exe`) then you'll have to remember that any JavaScript examples you find have to work with IE 11.

In the case of your HTA, please note that `IE=edge` means "run in the latest IE mode provided by MSHTML". It has nothing to do with the Edge browser. Since the latest MSHTML has been version 11 for a very long time (and will never go beyond that), you might as well specify `IE=11` to be more clear on what mode your HTA is in. Also, be aware that beyond `IE=9`, the `hta:application` section is ignored (which is why your HTA is not opening maximized).

But, as you probably discovered, the `range` input type requires `IE=10` or higher. Therefore, in order to use `range` AND `hta:application` attributes, you will need to split your HTA into two files, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68826015/15764378).

Comment: Thank you so much, a very elucidating and complete reply, which has cleared up other false ideas I was labouring under. I will heed your suggestions, they are very much appreciated! : )