# use a part of html tag src from script in a Hta (html application)

Tags: javascript, html, constants, src, hta

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9nin.png) I use css in my hta with ie=10.

Note: It should be noted that I am using this code as an HTA program, not on a web page

```
<script language = "vbscript" type = "text/vbscript">
         Const CNS="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=PhoneBook;Data Source=SERVER\SGMSQLSERVER2019;User ID=sa;Password=md13@48;"
         Const FinalPic="file:///d:/Webprojectk"
            
            public connect
            Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
             connect.ConnectionString = CNS
            connect.Open
         
      </script>
```

Now I want to use this static address for various tags such as CSS addresses and JavaScript files, etc. in the head abd body part of the page.

```
           <link rel="stylesheet" href= FinalPic  + "/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            
       <script src= FinalPic  + "/java/jquery.min.js"></script>
       
       <script LANGUAGE="VBScript" src= FinalPic  + "/vb/ed.vbs"></script>
       
          <img src=   FinalPic  + "/picture/ramadan.gif" style="width:10%">
```

Of course, I tried to do this, but apparently there is a problem and I can't use this variable in the HTML code. Please help me.

I put my complete and simple my code here. please look at here again:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION>
 </head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <!-----I put css  js vbs pictures and other files in different folders------->
        
        <link  href= path  + "/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src= path  + "/java/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script LANGUAGE="VBScript" src= path  + "/vb/ed.vbs"></script>
       

<script language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
    msgbox path  
End Sub
</script>

<body>

alert(path)
    <img src=   path  + "/picture/flower.gif" style="width:10%">
     <!--here  define what I want to call onload hta-->
   <script language = "vbscript" type = "text/vbscript">
         Const path="file:///d:/Webproject"
   </script>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's really difficult to help with just those snippets. If you could post a complete HTA (i.e. a minimal example that demonstrates the issue) that would help a lot. Are you aware that an HTA runs via MSHTML and that, by default, without any document type or mode declarations it will be running in IE 5 mode? And with the correct declarations the best you can do, using VBScript, is IE 10 mode and with JScript it would be IE 11 mode. You can't use modern HTML/CSS/JavaScript. That's a big reason why it helps to see a complete HTA script.

Comment: BTW, there's a password in the posted code. Hopefully that's not a password you've used elsewhere.

Comment: Tanks, its a fake password

Comment: sorry. I edit my  question please look at again.

Comment: It looks like you'd need [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element instead of some script variable.

Answer (score 1):

As @Teemu stated, you need to use a `<base>` element to set the resource path. See example below.

Also, note that `IE=10` mode does not support `<HTA:APPLICATION>`, so you can remove that line. If you need any features provided by that section, you will either need to drop down to `IE=9` or [split your file into two parts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68826015/15764378) or use the [VbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/) HTM to EXE feature.

Also watch your case. For example `Window_OnLoad` should be `window_onload`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
<base href="file:///C:/Resources/">
<link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="JScript" src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="VBScript" src = "vbs/ed.vbs"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src = "pic/flower.gif">
</body>
</html>
```