# Change Label Background Color with VBScript

Tags: html, css, vbscript

I have a HTA form where input type labels are set to `background-color: LightGray;` in the head CSS, and I would like to change the background color to another color during runtime based on a condition with VBScript. Condition code is fine (`If... Then... End If`)

Let's say the control's ID is "controlid".

I have tried stuff like

`controlid.style.BackColor = RGB(0,0,0)`

`controlid.style.bgColor = RGB(0,0,0)`

`controlid.style.BackColor = "0,0,0"`

`controlid.style.bgColor = "0,0,0"`

`controlid.BackColor = RGB(0,0,0)`

`controlid.bgColor = RGB(0,0,0)`

`controlid.BackColor = "0,0,0"`

`controlid.bgColor = "0,0,0"`

etcetera.

Google is not playing nice. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Examples: `controlid.style.backgroundColor = "DarkSlateBlue"` or `controlid.style.backgroundColor = "#3C3C3C"`. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colornames.asp)

Comment: Ensure your HTA starts with the correct declarations to run in either IE=9 or IE=10 mode for VBScript. Or possibly IE=11 mode if you change to JScript. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358044/15764378)

Comment: I'm using ```<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />``` with the various HTA forms I've made . All seem to work okay. I have started to move on to JScript, but I'm a VBA guy and VBScript is much easier for me to make stuff with. Nothing business critical fortunately.

Comment: Same for me, but I may use JScript more going forward. JScript works in IE=11 mode (giving access to the latest HTML/CSS offered by MSHTML), is easier to use with JSON data, has a sort routine built in, etc. Also, I have found that some HTAs, that are perfectly stable in IE=7 or IE=8 mode, [crash inconsistently, without error, when run in IE=9 or IE=10 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11759179/15764378). It's typically only an issue with very large, complex scripts and maybe only with VBScript. I think it's likely that using IE=11 mode with JScript would be stable for large complex scripts.

Comment: In general, IE=9 mode is used with HTAs because it gives access to a good HTML/CSS feature set and still supports the HTA:Application tag. But if you don't need to change any of the application tag defaults, you might as well use IE=10 (for VBScript) or IE=11 (for JScript). And if you do need an application tag setting and want to use IE=11 mode, you can get both capabilities by [splitting your script into two files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68826015/15764378).

Comment: Another very good option is to create HTML applications using [VbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com) (Use .htm extension instead of .hta). VbsEdit fully supports/encourages JScript with HTML applications, provides many great extensions (e.g. nice open/save dialogs), and generates EXEs that use MSHTML directly. That is, the EXEs will run on computers where MSHTA.exe has been blocked.

Comment: Yes, VbsEdit looks quite useful. The company I work for is barely beyond the Stone Age so MSHTA.exe hasn't been blocked, probably due to them probably not knowing what it is, but getting VbsEdit isn't going to happen either. Won't even let me install Visual Studio Community. PowerShell exists though, so that's something fun to play with.